# C# WPF CaliburnMicro Snapping location of UserControl to position on Monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, caliburn.micro

Snapping the location of a UserControl within a WPF Application using Caliburn Micro was a question that I spent a lot of time looking for an answer to.

Using a ShellView and Caliburn Micro there is a ShellView that is a WPF Window.  Adding to this involves adding "User Controls" that sit within that ShellView.

I spent a good amount of time trying to work out how to snap to a location on the monitor/screen while keeping my current view.

A lot of the answers involved WinForms - and the syntax did not transfer well and getting WinForms to even run on .NET 6 was more trouble than it was worth, just for this.

Finally I worked out an answer and I wanted to put it here as a more up to date answer to this question, in .NET 6 - not relying on Winforms and a little easier (hopefully) to find.

If anyone has any comments or improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The code that I used was within my Secondary viewmodel.

Main Window is ShellView with ShellViewModel MVVM, second view is FirstView and FirstViewModel.

Within the FirstViewModel, I placed the following code.  This snaps the WPF application to the Top Right corner while keeping the current view.

```
public void BtnAsyncStart()
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Right - System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Width;
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Top = 0;
}
```

This code snaps it back to the center on another button press.

```
public void BtnAsyncStop()
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / 2) - (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Width / 2);
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Top = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 2) - (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Height / 2);
}
```

Parts of this was gathered from various posts on Stack Overflow, so thanks to those contributors - but they were not put together for this purpose and were difficult to find.

Hopefully someone finds this useful.